# Debian Server failover setup

Tags: postgresql, replication, failover, debian

I need to set up two servers with failover capability (Active - Passive model) sharing a common DB (Postgres)running over NAS. Could you please suggest me some workaround for the same ?

Comment: what is the point of having active and passive DBs on a single NAS? it's better to keep them on separate datastores check [this link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling) for *sync* replication options.

Comment: This is not really something PostgreSQL wants to do (AFAIK, at least).  As said by Dmitry, there are better ways to have HA.